# google places api json response showing unavailability of a key- rating

Tags: android, json, google-places-api

I am working with google places api for nearby hotels search,in the JSON Response in case of some hotels there is "rating" key available and for some hotels the "rating" key is not available. so as the json parser cannot find the rating key for some json object-it halts parssing by giving error->

```
12-19 22:00:06.726 3811-3811/com.example.gplacesapp W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for rating
```

I want to include rating in the display list but I cannot do this..
How to solve this issue that The Hotels that have rating can be parsed and showed in the list accordingly and the hotels those do not have rating I can write unavailable there

Here is the JSON parsing code->

```
private ArrayList<Hotels> parseJson(String s) {
    if(hotellist!=null)
        hotellist.clear();
    if(s!=null){
        try {

            JSONObject jobj=new JSONObject(s);
            Log.i("MainActivity","Json Object is ->" +jobj.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),jobj.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            JSONArray jarr=jobj.getJSONArray("results");



            Log.i("MainActivity","No of elements : "+ jarr.length());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No of elements : "+ jarr.length(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            for (int i = 0; i < jarr.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject res = jarr.getJSONObject(i);
                Hotels wthr = new Hotels();

                String nam = res.getString("name");
                wthr.setName(nam);

                String rat = res.getString("rating");
                wthr.setRating(rat);

                String addr = res.getString("vicinity");
                wthr.setVicinity(addr);

                Log.i("MainActivity", "Name:" + nam);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Writing name : " + nam, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.i("MainActivity", "Rating:" + rat);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Writing rating : " + rat, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.i("MainActivity", "Vicinity:" + addr);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Writing Address : " + addr, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


            return hotellist;

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use '**has**' method to check whether key is present or not.

```
 if (res.has("name")) {
               String nam = res.getString("name");
                wthr.setName(nam);
}

 if (res.has("rating")) {
                String rat = res.getString("rating");
                wthr.setRating(rat);
}else{
 wthr.setRating(0);
}
```